# How do I fallback to previous versions of Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am having problem with the new update AS 1.1 Beta 2, Android Studio seems to stay as executing task, My always solution is restart(alt+ctr+delete) the IDE  and for at least 2 - 3 runs its back again(stays on executing task).

Is there any way that i could fallback to previous version? or should I uninstall and install Android studio?

Thanks

Comment: May be you have to uninstall AS.

Comment: yes i have done that many times, but seems like the update removes all of my settings including Compiler(Gradle -based Android Projects). the fix was setting it back to what it was(copying settings from stackoverflow answers) and thanks @GabrieleMariotti because if not uninstalling i would never find the root of the problem.